# How to modify <head> tag in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I've got flutter web up and running (pretty amazing work tbh) and I went about bench marking the Button Press Count app that it gives by default on PageSpeed Insights. The results were impressive but there's one suggestion that would seem to increase the score. Is there any way to include `<link rel='preload'>` for the assets they mentioned?

[image]

And would there be anyway to do code splitting as well the way webpack does it for `main.dart.js`
[image]

See the website here: https://flutterdemoapp.netlify.app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add this  code to your index.html file which is under the web folder,

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel='preload'>
   <script defer type="application/javascript" src="main.dart.js"></script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

If you already tried that or this doesn't work so you can use this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/preload). It makes this automatically.